# Запятая перед "соответственно"

Tags: пунктуация

Поясните, пожалуйста, почему ставится запятая перед словом "соответственно":

> Рост цен на продовольственные товары в 2019 году был ниже общего
> уровня и составил 7,8% и 6,1%, соответственно.

Comment: Потому что ошибка

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В данном случае причин ставить запятую здесь нет, она лишняя.